# Software developer vs Software engineer

Tags: resume, software-industry, career-development

I have BSc in applied math and computer science. And master's degree in Computer Science and Engineering.

I am interested when can one use title Software Engineer and when can he/she call himself software developer in CV?

Which title should I (or am I allowed to) use?

ps I don't think the company I work for now has strong preference for one or other title. But I am asking also in general.

It appears there are some restrictions when someone can call herself/himself engineer. So would be very much interested when is this case?

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager No in difference to that question I gave my background information. Plus the answer there is not very definitive. maybe we can solicit a better answer here

Comment: It's still the same question, and like that one, off topic - "This question does not appear to be about the workplace within the scope defined in the help center."  The basic fact is you can call yourself what you like, but just make sure it doesn't cause an issue if you get a background check.  In reality there is no hard/fast difference in engineer/developer.  In many industries it matters (where you need accreditation to be an engineer), but it tends to be used interchangeably in software.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Exactly  I was interested if there are some constraints when can one call herself/himself an engineer?

Comment: I think I said Nope.

Comment: As a development manager, my take would be an engineer is someone who takes a spec and writes some optimal code.  A developer is someone who can take a story/use case etc and see it through from requirements, coding testing etc.  So if I worked at NASA I'd want engineers, if I worked in another company, I'd want developers, so spin yourself according to what kind of work you want.

Comment: Note that in Texas, you cannot call yourself an engineer [unless you are currently a licensed engineer](https://engineers.texas.gov/software.html).

Comment: @user200312 the answers to the other question are not very definitive because there is no definitive answer to this question

Comment: "I am interested when can one use title Software Engineer ... in CV" - If you worked at a company where that company gave you the title of "Software Engineer", then you should put "Software Engineer" on your CV to indicate that position.

Comment: Does it count as the question's already having an answer if none of the answers are marked correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think the term Engineer should be reserved.  In Canada you can't put Engineer in your title without a license:

> In Canada it is illegal to practice engineering, or use the title
>   "professional engineer", without a license. Engineering in Canada is
>   regulated in the public interest by self-governing professional
>   licensing bodies. These bodies were established by Canada's 13
>   provincial and territorial governments through legislation. The
>   provincial and territorial governments have delegated their
>   constitutional authority to regulate engineers and engineering in
>   Canada to professional licensing bodies that are maintained and
>   governed by the profession, creating a system of self-regulation.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_and_licensure_in_engineering#Title_usage

My undergraduate is Mechanical Engineer, and Masters is Software Engineer.  I bristle when they give some secretary in another group the title of Industrial Engineer when their background is that they gather up drawing files and have no formal education.

Comment: If they're a more senior level person, and they show an aptitude for design, then feel free to designate them a Software Architect.

Comment: so maybe software developer is better to use? though in my case I thought soft. engineer also applies. Soft developer doesn't sound too bad though either

Comment: I like that answer.  I have people working for me that have the same graduate degree (MS Software Engineer).  They have Senior Software Developer as their title in the workplace.

Comment: The legal hurdles to putting "engineer" in your title are really only practically relevant to the company that gives your title. If a company offers you a position of "Software Engineer", are you going to turn it down because you don't have an engineering license? If two companies give you offers, one offering the title "SW Engineer", and one offering the title "SW Developer", is the title itself going to be your deciding factor of which offer to take?

Comment: @user200312 Not sure what the developer's body condition has to do with the job.